# Change default on login url

Tags: 7, users

How do I change Drupal's default on login url from `/user/<uid>` to `/user/<uid>/edit` so that a user gets to there right after they log in?

**EDITED:**
Tried [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules):

> Events: User has logged in.
>
> Condition: User has role.
>
> Actions: Page redirect to user/[current-user:uid]/edit

For some reason it doesn't work.

Tried [Login Destination](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination). Redirects work, but the module doesn't support tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do this with Rules:

> Events: User has logged in.
>
> Condition: -
>
> Actions: Page redirect to user/[account:uid]/edit